# Stripping HTML but retaining block/inline structure

Tags: html, filter, text-processing, text-extraction, text-formatting

I would like to convert HTML to plain text but retain the minimum structure.

- All sections which contain stuff only the browser needs to see such as <script> and <style> to be stripped completely.
- Convert all block tags to <div> and all inline ones to <span> **or** remove inlines completely without leaving whitespace and turning anything delineatd by block levels into paragraphs with two linebreaks.

The idea is to turn random web pages into something suitable for natural language text processing without artefacts left from naively removing markup artifically break words up or making unrelated blocks look like sentences.

Any binary, library, or source in any programming language is OK.

Is there a standard source preferably machine-readable with a full list of elements defining which are block, which inline, and which are like <script> and <style> above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own tool to solve this problem in Perl using HTML::Parser as a github gist: [html2txt.pl](https://gist.github.com/751910)

It's unfinished and perhaps slightly Windows-centric but I thought I'd share it since a few people have viewed my question here. Feel free to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

The list of HTML 4 Block-level elements is here: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html

The most popular HTML parsing libraries for Perl are [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser) which is a SAX-style parser and [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder) which is more DOM-like.

Beyond that, you'll have to decide which elements are important and which are not based on what you're trying do to.

Comment: thanks for the list. I ended up using the HTML 4 DTD but not all elements were marked, including tr and td. Also some live pages still use deprecated tags such as marquee, center, and even flash. I might have to consult the source for some web browsers...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some research yourself. Then, when you run into a problem, ask a question related to the problem.  This sounds more like specification for a project that you want someone to do for you.

For starters, websites use tags for all sorts of things, and the problem is very complex.  You would probably want to save information in h# and p tags, but you also may want to save div tag information if they use the id tag.  In short, you'd have to write rules for each website you encounter, or employ some sort of fuzzy logic.

Instead of doing it on a tag by tag basis, why not try detecting sentences and grammar, or things likely to be in headings, and choose tags that include those things while stripping out the rest?

Comment: I don't mind doing the programming myself. I've researched the HTML parsers for my primary language, Perl, but none seem to provide data for the elements that tell me whether they are inline, block, etc. I also looked for specific Perl modules that might offer this info to no avail. So possibly I missed such a parser or module, or there are better parsers or libraries available for other programming languages. Stripping HTML is pretty commonplace so a tool with a few options may exist that I haven't been able to find on my own yet. The grammar way won't work because I deal with many languages.